# Difference between > and >> when used with a named pipe

Tags: io-redirection, fifo

Is there any difference between the two redirections in the following code?

```
mkfifo foo
echo > foo  
echo >> foo
```

Comment: `mkfifo:  difference between > and >>` would look clearer

Answer (score 8):

There *should* be no difference. The `>>` will open the fifo with the `O_APPEND` flag, and that shouldn't make any difference on a fifo or other non-seekable file.

*However*, there are buggy interfaces like `sendfile(2)` in Linux, which do not work with files opened in `O_APPEND` mode, and will object even to non-seekable files having that mode set, so you better always use the `>` form.

Answer (score -3):

`>` overwrites the destination file

`>>` appends to the destination file

Thanks to [Jobin](https://askubuntu.com/users/72576/jobin) at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382793/whats-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-command) for the authoritative answer with 45 likes.

Comment: Notice that the redirections are used with a named pipe in the question, not a regular file.  The question is whether `>` and `>>` has the same effect.